# Motherboard LEDs blink but it won't turn on

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have a PC that does not turn on. I checked all the pins of the power supply with a multimeter and they are ok. I tried to connect the motherboard only: the two LEDs (power and reset) blink, but if I press the power button nothing happens (even the CPU fan does not spin). How can I identify the problem?

Comment: Did this all of a sudden just occur or what has happened before leading up to this?

Comment: Wild guess but I can't put as a comment because of reputation. Is the power button connected correctly?

Comment: I don't know but I tried the power button of the motherboard directly (the one with the blinking LED)

Comment: This is a PC another person used, until it stopped working. I think it happened suddenly.

Comment: Try following these steps here: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/284154-30-computer-turn-onboard-power-switch-flashing It's also strange how there would be a power button on the motherboard directly. Are you sure it's power?

Comment: Thanks, I will try. It is an ASUS P5Q Deluxe motherboard. There are two onboard switches (power-on and reset)

Comment: Did Post ( Power on selftest completed ) ?. Does any sequence of beep sound heard from the mother board speaker ?. Replace the motherboard battery and check, this also one of the issue.

Comment: I don't think so because I did not hear any sound. I tried to use one RAM at a time, in every possible slot but nothing changed. I tested the battery with the multimeter and it is still alive. Should I replace it anyway?

Comment: It could still be the Power supply. Try another power supply to rule it out.